# Web tool for testing website IPv6 readiness

Tags: ipv6

With [World IPv6 Day](http://test-ipv6.com/) fast approaching, I have set up the protocol on my VPS. I think everything is ready to go, but since ISP (Insight) does not yet offer IPv6 addresses to residential customers, I have no way of confirming this myself. Does anyone know if there is a tool for testing the IPv6 readiness of websites, similar to the [IPv6 test](http://www.worldipv6day.org/) tool for for workstations?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php seems to work quite well.

Answer (score 1):

If you ant to test from your home I suggest to get an account from one of the tunnel brokers. I've had good success with [SIXXS](http://www.sixxs.net). It's not an optimal solution but works fairly well under the major operating systems and brings you the benefit of being able to get an entire subnet at home so you can test all your devices for IPv6 readiness (and participate for yourself in the World IPv6 Day)